# Bring multiple background element to the front

Tags: html, css, background, foreground

I'm currently working on a hobby website, and I'm trying to accomplish something which seems way more advanced that it should be, I hope you can help me.

I wish to bring a background element, du the foreground (Because a little bit of it should reach on top of the menu line)

I am using the CSS3 multiple background method, to use 3 different background elements. I have included the code and an image to show what I man.

Cheers

```
background-image:url(logo.png), url(shinybg.png), url(bgpat.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat, repeat;
background-position:top center, top 18px center, top left;
height:1000px;
padding-top:10px;
z-index:-1
```

Image: http://goo.gl/JEvhAz

EDIT:
Okay so it seems I fixed it. I made the img tag outside of my wrapper and made it position absolute, the way to center it was as follow:

```
#logotop {
    width: 905px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:-18px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

The left and right 0 together with the margin 0 auto fixed it, cheers lads

Comment: Can you also include your html, or set up a fiddle showcasing the issue?

Comment: @OP are you trying to make the "points" of your logo go over the top of the grey area?

Comment: Assuming you want to put the 'points' over the grey part, you can just give the image a higher z-index than the grey box. Obviously ensure the image is a PNG with no background colour to achieve the full effect.

Comment: @NikkiMather It would need to be a separate element in that case. You couldn't use the multiple backgrounds CSS3 offers.

Comment: Background images do not take Z-index...they are in the background by definition. If you need to overlap elements they must be inline (in the HTML).

Comment: Apologies, the assumption was that he would be using an image instead of a background image. I missed mentioning that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your header image/logo into a new `<img>` tag that is placed on top of your page. This will give you much more control over positioning than what you're currently doing, and will allow you to use z-index.

If you're comfortable with HTML/CSS, I'd recommend creating a header `<div>` and set the background on that div (and also the z-index). This will allow you more options further down the line but the simpler option is to use the `<img>` tag.

Here is a jsFiddle with some examples that might help you: http://jsfiddle.net/tMhs7/1/

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, however now I'm having trouble centering my logo.. Heres my CSS

body img {
 position:absolute;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -18px;
 z-index:-1;
}

Comment: No problem. I've created a JSFiddle with some examples to help you along. I hope they help!